Calculating an integral using the mean value theorem
In the book Recherches analytiques sur la théorie des nombres premiers by Charles-Jean de La Vallée Poussin, in page 12, he states:

$"$One can easily deduce from the second mean value theorem that:
for $y>1$, $$\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\log y} e^{(a+k)t}\frac{\sin(bt)}{t}dt=1;$$
for $y=1$, $$\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\log y} e^{(a+k)t}\frac{\sin(bt)}{t}dt=\frac{1}{2};$$
for $y<1$, $$\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\log y} e^{(a+k)t}\frac{\sin(bt)}{t}dt=0."$$

I have tried to understand this by looking at various formulations of the mean value theorem, but really can't seem to be able to get to the bottom of this. Can someone help me?

Hint. Instead of using the second mean value theorem, you can derive those results using the fact that, as a distribuition,
$$
\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac{\sin(bt)}{\pi t}=\delta(t),
$$
where $\delta(\cdot)$ is the Dirac delta distribution (see here).

Applying MVII directly, I hit the same problem as @F_M_. The key is to split the integral around 0 and deal with each half separately.
MVII says

If $f$ is monotone on $[α,β]$ and $ϕ$ is integrable on $[α,β]$, there exists $ξ∈(α,β)$ such that
$$\int^{β}_{α}f(t)ϕ(t)dt=f(α)\int^{ξ}_{α}ϕ(t)dt+f(β)\int^β_ξϕ(t)dt$$

With $\alpha=-\infty$ and $f(t) = e^{(a+k)t}$ (noting of course $a+k>0$), the first integral on the RHS is definitely 0. Therefore we have (making the sub $u=bt$),
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\beta}e^{(a+k)t}\frac{\sin(bt)}{t}dt = e^{(a+k)\beta}\int_{\xi}^{\beta}\frac{\sin(bt)}{t}dt = e^{(a+k)\beta}\int_{b\xi}^{b\beta}\frac{\sin(u)}{u}du$$
Now the $b$ dependency is pushed into just the integral limits. Note the elementary integrals
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(u)}{u}du = 2\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{\sin(u)}{u}du = \pi.$$
So all we have to do is determine which side of 0 the integral bounds are on. If $\beta = \log(y) < 0$, then both bounds are negative and tending to $-\infty$ - so the final answer is $0$, as expected. If $\beta = \log(y) = 0$, then the bottom bound is tending to $-\infty$ and the top one is 0, so we get $\pi/2$, again as expected. If $\beta>1$ then we can't tell, because $\xi$ might be positive or negative.
So take $y>1$, and split the integral up into $t<0$ and $t>0$. We already calculated the $t<0$ integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\log(y)} e^{(a+k)t} \frac{\sin(bt)}{t}dt = \left(\to \frac{\pi}{2}\right) + \int_{0}^{\log(y)} e^{(a+k)t} \frac{\sin(bt)}{t}dt$$
and, applying the theorem a second time, and again letting $u=bt$,
$$\int_{0}^{\log(y)} e^{(a+k)t} \frac{\sin(bt)}{t}dt = \int_{0}^{\xi'}\frac{\sin(bt)}{t}dt + y^{a+k}\int_{\xi'}^{\log(y)}\frac{\sin(bt)}{t}dt \to \frac{\pi}{2} + 0$$

This is only a partial answer for the case $y=1.$
Let us denote
$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^{\log y} e^{(a+k)t} \frac{\sin(bt)}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t,
$$
where we assume $b>0$ (based on the wanted limit) and $\Re(a+k)>0$ (as in said book).
Consider the function
$$
S(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{\sin(bt)}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t . 
$$
One can show that $S(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} + \text{Si}(bx)$, where $\text{Si}$ is the trigonometric integral
$$
\text{Si}(x) = \int_0^x \frac{\sin(t)}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t,
$$
with $\text{Si}(x)\to \frac{\pi}{2}$ as $x \to\infty.$ Note that also (use a substitution)
$$
\int_0^x \frac{\sin(bt)}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t = \text{Si}(bx).
$$
Applying the second mean value theorem on $I$ we obtain that there is some $c \in ]-\infty, \log y [,$ such that
\begin{align*}
I  &= \lim\limits_{s\to - \infty}  e^{(a+k)s} \int_{-\infty}^c \frac{\sin(bt)}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t + e^{(a+k) \log y} \int_{c}^{\log y} \frac{\sin(bt)}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t \\
 &= 0 \cdot \left(\frac{\pi}{2} + \text{Si}(bc)  \right) + e^{(a+k)\log y}\left(\text{Si}(b\log y) - \text{Si}(bc)\right) 
\end{align*}
Focussing on the case $y=1,$ then $\log y = 0$ and we have (since $c<0$)
$$
\lim\limits_{b\to\infty} I = \text{Si}(0) - \text{Si}(bc) = 0 - \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)= \frac{\pi}{2},
$$
which gives the stated result after division by $\pi.$
At the moment, I am a bit puzzled why in the other cases, the limit does not depend on $y.$

For $y<1$ you can see that $\int_{c}^{\log y} \ldots$ is an integral with both limit $\to -\infty$, so it must be 0. However in the case where $y>1$ I have the same result as you. I think the value is actually $y^{a+k}\pi$ in this case, and I can't see where we're making a mistake.

Using the theorem that can be found at the bottom of page 13 of the same book, basically a more compact version of what was used in this answer, I was able to obtain the cases $y<1$ and $y=0$, while for the case $y>1$ I have found that the result depends on the value $c$ ($\xi$ in the theorem that appears in the original text)  if it is true that $c<0$ then we actually obtain the result $y^{a+k}\pi$ which I have to assume is the right one at this point.
$\$
I would really like to know if the text  is actually wrong

The limit of $bc$ as $b\to \infty$ is not necessarily trivial because $c$ depends on $b$ as well.

You can tell the answer provided in the text must be correct, because the distribution-based answer from Goncalo is actually completely rigorous - the exponential term (not a schwartz function) can be cut off above $\log(y)$ to give an actually schwartz function.
